# Search for specific word in text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently trying to search for a specific word in a text file.
I've already wrote my code but it seems that the script is not working correctly.

My code:

```
main_file = open('myfile.txt','w')
        

x = 'Hello'
x_main = main_file.write(x)
with open('myfile.txt') as f:
    datafile = f.readlines()
for line in datafile:
    if 'Hello' in line: #I also tried Hello without the quotes
        print("ok")
print(x)
```

I get only Hello as an output and not ok + Hello.

I hope that someone can help me out with this little problem:)

Thank's for every help and suggestion in advance:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main problem is that you don't close the file after your file after writing to it. Like you have done to open your file `with open(file) as file` you can do the same in order to read the file. This way you avoid the hastle of writing `file.close()`.

Other than that, your code seems fine.

```
with open('test.txt','w') as f:
    x = 'Hello'
    f.write(x)
with open('test.txt') as f:
    datafile = f.readlines()
for line in datafile:
    if 'Hello' in line: #I also tried Hello without the quotes
        print("ok")
print(x)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this one

```
main_file = open('myfile.txt','w')
    
x = 'Hello'
x_main = main_file.write(x)
main_file.close()
with open('myfile.txt', 'r') as f:
   datafile = f.readlines()
for line in datafile:
   if 'Hello' in line: #I also tried Hello without the quotes
      print("ok")
print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

When writing to your file, you never closed the file (`file.close()`). I would suggest using the `open()` context manager so you don't have to worry about writing `file.close()`.

```py
string = "Hello"
with open("myfile.txt", "w") as file:
    file.write(string)

with open("myfile.txt") as file:
    lines = file.readlines()

for line in lines:
    if "Hello" in line:
        print("OK")

print(string)
```